# ElasticSearch Multi Match with Multiple Query Parameters

Tags: elasticsearch

We have the following multi match query in Elastic Search

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "90803",
                "type": "cross_fields",
                "fields": [
                    "POSTAL_CODE^5",
                    "ADDRESS",
                    "CITY"
                ],
                "operator": "and"
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

How can we pass multiple query parameters. For e.g. we want to pass multiple ID in the query to match against the field Postal Code.

Comment: You can just do "query": "90803 90804" but that's assuming postal code field contains multiple (or the combination of 3 fields if they all use the same analyzer). Maybe you are looking for best_fields with or operator

Comment: Could you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

First, is `POSTAL_CODE` an analyzed field? If it's not the case you could use a [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html):

```
{
    "query": {
        "terms" : { 
            "POSTAL_CODE" : ["90803", "90809"]
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use Match for some reason, there is not a Match Query that matches several values, you have to use a `Bool Query` with `should` or `must` depending on your use case.

Example with `must`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match": { "POSTAL_CODE": "90803" }
            }, {
                "match": { "POSTAL_CODE": "90809" }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```